# Flex Drag and Drop

Tags: apache-flex, drag-and-drop, air, flexbuilder

I am trying to do a flex drag and drop. It is very similar to this first example. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dragdrop_7.html

The problem is that event.currentTarget.mouseX,mouseY is showing the position where I put the mouse down rather than the position where I had finished dragging.

I am just wondering why this could be? If there is a short answer?

Comment: Just an update. This works in an Application but not a WindowedApplication.

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean the code works as expected in Application, but in WindowedApplication event.currentTarget.mouseX & Y show the position where you put the  mouse down? Does this happen both in flex/flash and also in the live air app?

Comment: It seems it is a Adobe Air Bug, it works in the browser but not in a Application. I found a workaround using a timer event.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that Flex-on-AIR and Flex-in-Browser apps have different DragManager implementations and that behavior is not entirely consistent between these two environments.